# Deleting lines matching a pattern and put them into the buffer

Tags: cut-copy-paste, global-command

I am trying to do this: deleting lines matching a pattern and then copy these lines into some other place in the file.

```
:g/PATTERN/d
```

does delete the lines but when I use p or P, only the last line is inserted to the file from the internal buffer.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could delete the lines in a register:

First clean up your register `q` for example with `qqq` in normal mode.

Then use `:g/PATTERN/norm! "Qdd`

In normal mode when you use `"qdd` you replace the content of the `q` register with the deleted text but if you use `"Qdd` you append the deleted text to the register.

**EDIT** As @Matt pointed out in the comments you don't need to use the `norm!` trick in you global command because `:d` also accepts a register as a parameter ([`:h :d`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Ad)) so you can simply use

```
:g/PATTERN/d Q
```

You can then use `"qp` to past the content of the register where your want to.

---

Another solution is to combine [`:h :move`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Amove) with the global command. For example to move all the matching lines at the end of the buffer:

```
:g/PATTERN/move $
```

Comment: `d Q` is enough. No need for "normal".

Comment: Thank @Matt I completely forgot about this syntax for `:d` and didn't take the time to look at the doc! I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you get only the last line back is that `:g` works on the found lines line by line. This means that every next delete operation overwrites the previous content of the register used.

To overcome this you must use a named register (`A`-`Z`) and use the uppercase name, which causes the new content not overwriting the previous one but appending to the register.

```
g/PATTERN/d A
```

will append all deleted lines to the register `a`.

Now that register will not be empty, so you must clear its contents before using it.

`qaq` will start to record a macro into register `a` and immediately stop again, thus clearing its contents.